# Change the status of more than one option in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I want to change the status of more than one option
In the picture, select the columns in which I want to change, then click on the modal and choose the state, then click on Change and the state of all the selected is changed to the selected state
How is that in Laravel?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a frontend thing. However, that being said, please provide more detail and code.

Answer (score 0):

Inthe blade add

```
<table> <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat" ></th>  </table>
```

Inthe Modal

```
 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
```

inthe Ajax

```
 $(document).on('click', '#update', function(){

var id = [];
$('.status:checked').each(function(){
  id.push($(this).attr('id'));

          });
  $('#form_result').html('');   

$.ajax({
 url:"/order/"+id+"/edit",
 dataType:"json",
 success:function(html){ 
 $('#status_id').val(html.data.status_id); 
  $('#hidden_id').val(html.data.id);
   
 }
})
});
```

In controller

```
->addIndexColumn()
      ->addColumn('show', function($data){
        $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" id="'.$data->id.'" class="all print" />';
      
        return $checkbox;
```

You have to send ids as hidden inthe checkboxes.
Inthe controller you can use it

```
$ids_edit = explode(',', $request->hidden_id);


        foreach($ids_edit as $id){
            if($id){
                $order =Order::find($id);
                $order->status_id = $request->status_id; 
                $order->update();
                }
           }
```

Comment: I am send the ID through the datatable
return '<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="'.$row->id.'"/>';
How do I continue?

Comment: yes you have to send ids through ajax for editing as hidden_ids then you status[] will be updated from your modal where i can see "جديد"  as status to be updated.

Comment: how to send ids ajax for editing as hidden_ids  ?

Comment: With the blade file
You added this line inside the form
                        <input type="hidden" value="" id="orders_ids" name="orders_ids">
Is that true?